# How to enable inPrivate mode in the WebBrowser control 

Tags: c#, winforms, web-applications, webbrowser-control

I have to make a IE type browser with some extra features on it.

In Visual Studio, we have a component named "WebBrowser" that uses current IE browser installed in user's pc.

However, I am unable to find any property that enables access to the InPrivate mode I hoped would be exposed by control.

Is there a way to use InPrivate mode  with the WebBrowser control, or would I have to make my own browser that supports this?

Comment: You need to give us more information about this component, what company makes its ?

Comment: You mean this [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx)?

Comment: hi Smudge202thanks for ur quick reply. Yeah I mean  WebBrowser

Comment: Well I search your answer for the same problem and found that there is no such thing then I came up a solution using different window accounts for each webbrowser control.

Answer (score 2):

According to [EricLaw's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594686/webbrowser-control-isolation-and-ie8-inprivate-mode/1618781#1618781) on a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594686/webbrowser-control-isolation-and-ie8-inprivate-mode), it sounds like this might not be possible.

You might be stuck making your own control or looking for an alternative one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that will give you access to an InPrivate IE

```
Friend Function Open(Optional ByVal Url As String = "about:blank", Optional ByVal WindowState As ProcessWindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden) As WebBrowser
On Error Resume Next

Dim Start As New ProcessStartInfo
Dim Windows = New ShellWindowsClass
Dim Count = Windows.Count
Start.FileName = "iexplore.exe"
Start.Arguments = "-private -nomerge " & Url
If WindowState = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden Then
  Start.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized
Else
  Start.WindowStyle = WindowState
End If
Process.Start(Start)

'Wait is my own class that waits for 10 secs
Wait.Reset()
Do
  If Windows.Count > Count Then Exit Do
Loop While Wait.Waiting

Browser = Windows(Count)
Browser.Visible = (WindowState <> ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden)
Return Browser
End Function
```

Comment: Good information on InPrivate, but doesn't answer the question. The OP needs this for the Windows Forms WebBrowser control.

Comment: "or would I have to make my own browser that supports this" You can create your own with the return from this function. I'm assuming that anyone who wants to make their own browser has some idea how to do that.

Comment: I think that's a bad assumption. This could simply be someone who has been _told_ that he wants to make his own browser.

Comment: Not an assumption, it was in the question - have you nothing better to do?