# Without Caching in WebBrowser / Private Browsing like IE

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable private browsing like IE8 in C#.net using Webbrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675864/how-to-enable-private-browsing-like-ie8-in-c-net-using-webbrowser-control)

On Visual Studio C# .NET , we have a component named "WebBrowser" that uses current IE browser installed in user's pc. but m unable to find any property that enable private browsing... is there any way how to use private browsing in my program? or i have to make my own InPrivate browser????

Comment: Oh, how I really hate the WebBrowser IE-wrapper :(