# C#: Stop sharing IE cache and sessions for multiple logins?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, console-application

I am trying to run multiple browsers in multiple threads and login to a website on seperate accounts. The issue I currently face is the browsers are sharing sessions so it can never login to multiple accounts because its sharing accounts between it, I guess its somehow sharing the Internet Explorer cache and sessions.

Is there a way I can avoid a problem like this?

Comment: Have you tried to start each instance as private browsing?  This should avoid the cookie sharing issue.

Answer (score 0):

Everytime that you open an IE instance do it in private mode:

```
iexplore.exe -private
```

or from another IE instance:

> To open an InPrivate Browsing window, you can either use the Ctrl+Shift+P shortcut key, or just use the Safety \ InPrivate Browsing item on the menu. On more modern versions of IE, you can find that through the Gear icon, and then Safety \ InPrivate Browsing as seen below.

Hope this help!

Comment: I'm not starting IE, I am using the WebBrowser control.

Comment: Then your question needs to be different, no?

Comment: Have heard about Selenium Web Driver? Looks like a better approach if you are benchmarking.

Comment: Look at this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675864/how-to-enable-inprivate-mode-in-the-webbrowser-control
What are you trying maybe is impossible.