# Multiple WebBrowsers on same form with different sessions VB

Tags: vb.net, session, webbrowser-control

Hello I'm looking for a way to have 2 or more webbrowsers on one form using different sessions aka meaning I can log on to the same site on two different accounts.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594686/webbrowser-control-isolation-and-ie8-inprivate-mode), along with ShellWindows and MSHTML activex libraries should do the trick.