# Running multiple WebBrowsers independent of each other

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, webbrowser-control, web-controls, isolation

I have a Windows application developed in C# 4.0 and I am using multiple WebBrowser controls in it where all the WebBrowsers load the same website URL and perform some kind of search by setting the search value in the textbox and clicking the search button.

All the WebBrowsers are supposed search for different keywords at a time. They work correctly when each runs individually, but the moment all of then run together, they are all searching for the same keyword instead of different ones! And the keyword isn't that of the first/last one; it's a randomly chosen one. I have implemented the code inside DocumentCompleted.

I believe the website itself is identifying one of the keywords searched first and setting it in all WebBrowser windows. Is there a way to run all these WebBrowsers in isolation and in parallel so that each "session" doesn't affect the other?

Answer (score 1):

`WebBrowser` control uses URLMon Windows library, which shares the HTTP session on per-process basis (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1594686)). Thus, all your instances of `WebBrowser` control operate on the same session.

To my knowledge, the only way to make possible what you're after with `WebBrowser` would be to use multi-process architecture, with each `WebBrowser` living in its own process.