# Prevent a WebBrowser object from creating history

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have a project for a client where that will take a piece of customer information and use that to open a web browser. They're currently doing this by having a button open a the URL ("http://server.com/?customerID=XYZ") in the default browser. However, they don't like this solution, as their users have a tendency to leave this (very confidential) information on their screens for longer than necessary, and it leaves the link in the browser's history, so the user can open it again and again.

The solution was a request for an application that would open the link instead in a separate windows form with no navigation available to the user, and would automatically close after a set period of time.  I have that piece working fine, but opening the link in a WebBrowser object in my form still inserts the link into IE's browser history.

I can't find any solution to making the WebBrowser object private or deleting the history that works in C#, so any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1)  It sounds like the application should have some sort of security/timeouts to require logins and then timeout and log out after a period of time to no longer display the info.  2) using the javascript `location.replace(url)` prevents history, but not sure if that'll work for you since you're using a WebBrowser control in a WinForms application it sounds like and by default there's no way to prevent history from being written from a direct link.

Comment: Yeah. The only other option I've come up with is to possibly open a new IE process in kiosk and private mode. That would probably work, but I'm not sure if there's then a way to close that after 30 seconds.

Comment: I'm not sure if you'll be able to close it after inactivity in that window since your application won't be aware of what events are occurring in it, but you can definitely track the process you created and then kill it after X minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up launching an inPrivate window and opening the form in that.  My form then looks for the iexplore.exe process and kills it at the end of the 30 seconds.

```
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\program files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe","-private " + _url);
```

Then, when the timer is finished:

```
            var procs = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(_name);
            foreach (var proc in procs)
            {
                proc.Kill();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594686/webbrowser-control-isolation-and-ie8-inprivate-mode/1618781#1618781) is an old post where they say that a private mode is not possible. So you probably can't deactivate the browser history.

One solution would be to close the form after the amount of time and invalidate the data such that the url can't be reopened.

You can do it with Javascript:

Set a timeout on your page that is calling a special Url (with whatever syntax)

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
        window.location.href = 'special_close'; 
        }, 30000);
```

Then you can intercept this url in the WebBrowsers Navigating event and close the form:

```
 private void Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
 {
      if (e.Url.OriginalString == "special_close")
      {
            // close form that contains webbrowser
            // invalidate data here such that url can't be reloaded
      }
 }
```

Comment: I found that, too. I'm at lunch now, but I'm thinking of trying something where I launch Internet Explorer in InPrivate mode instead of doing it in my own form. I'll have to find a way to close that after the 30 seconds, though.